# Can you guys help me with writing a DOCKER FILE

Tags: docker, apache2, devops, mysql-8.0, php-7.4

Can you guys help me with writing a docker file for php7.4 ,apache 2 and mysql8 running on a single container ! with MySQL database configurations included in the file !

Comment: [ask] in the SO help center has some advice on writing a clear, answerable question.  The setup you're describing isn't a typical Docker best practice and you'd almost always run your database in a separate container, maybe using a tool like Docker Compose to launch the two containers together; if you do that you can use the `mysql:8` and `php:7.4-apache` images as your base.

Comment: @DavidMaze can you please elobarate ?? if they run on different containers can they communicate and work with each other properly ??

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/ has lots of material, including a set of [Sample Applications](https://docs.docker.com/samples/) that demonstrate some typical patterns and documentation on [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Answer (score 1):

By using `--privileged` flag to `docker run`, you can use docker inside your docker container as well.

Follow these steps:

- run a simple ubuntu base docker container with `privileged` flag.
- pull all images you want and config them as you wish (php, apache, etc.)
- commit the ubuntu running container.
- write a Dockerfile and use the committed image as base.
- write cmd for the image to run all services on run.
- build the Dockerfile.